# How to support loop drawing in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
data <- data.frame(a=1:10, b=1:10 * 2, c=1:10 * 3)

library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(NULL, aes(x = 1:10))

# Using for loop will cause the plot only to draw the last line.
for (i in names(data)){
  p <- p + geom_line(aes(y = data[[i]], colour = i))
}

# Lines below works fine.
# p <- p + geom_line(aes(y = data[["a"]], colour = "a"))
# p <- p + geom_line(aes(y = data[["b"]], colour = "b"))
# p <- p + geom_line(aes(y = data[["c"]], colour = "c"))

print(p)
```

Why loop plotting doesn't work as what we expected?

Is this a lazy plotting method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't actually have to loop to get your lines. You just need to reshape your data and actually include x in your data frame.  Your data is wide, and ggplot2 likes long data.  This is how you can easily make multiple lines in a single plot.

As an aside, your method doesn't work as you are replacing `p` each time you iterate, ending up with only the endpoint of the loop.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

data <- data.frame(x = 1:10, a=1:10, b=1:10 * 2, c=1:10 * 3)

df <- gather(data, name, value, -x)

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = value, color = name)) +
   geom_line()
```

[image]